# Python csv with less separators than necessary

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with errors. Some rows have 4 separators (;), while most part of the rows have 5 separators (;). The reason why I have sometimes 4 separators is because sometimes the 2nd column is missing.

Example:

```
var1;var2;var3;var4;var5
1;10;john;40;56
2;mary;34;78
3;90.0;smith;52;45
```

If I import the csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=";")
```

I obtain the dataframe:

```
var1 var2  var3  var4 var5
1    10    john  40   56
2    mary  34    78
3    90.0  smith 52   45
```

and I want:

```
var1 var2  var3  var4 var5
1    10    john  40   56
2    NaN   mary  34    78
3    90.0  smith 52   45
```

Maybe I could split the dataframe into two parts (one with 5 ";", another with 4 ";") and append in the end.
I started with the code:

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv',newline='') as fin, open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 4:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

but I obtain the error: "line contains NUL".

Comment: Do you always have numbers except for the second column?

Comment: No, not always. The 1st and 2nd column have always numbers, but in the 2nd column sometimes I have e.g. "10.0", the 3rd column is the title of something (it has words, sometimes punctuation)

Comment: OK, anyway I provided a more generic approach

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be to [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) part of the DataFrame:

```
# read with shifted columns
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=';')

# identify rows with incorrect data
m = df['var5'].isna()
# define columns to correct (second to last)
cols = df.columns[1:]

# correct the invalid rows
df.loc[m, cols] = df.loc[m, cols].shift(axis=1)
```

output:

```
   var1  var2   var3 var4  var5
0     1    10   john   40  56.0
1     2  None   mary   34  78.0
2     3  90.0  smith   52  45.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You might preprocess `file.csv` inserting `;` if needed following way, let `file.csv` content be

```
var1;var2;var3;var4;var5
1;10;john;40;56
2;mary;34;78
3;90.0;smith;52;45
```

then

```
with open("file.csv","r") as fin, open("file_fixed.csv","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.count(';') == 3:
            line = line.replace(';',';;',1)
        fout.write(line)
```

does create file_fixed.csv with following content

```
var1;var2;var3;var4;var5
1;10;john;40;56
2;;mary;34;78
3;90.0;smith;52;45
```

Explanation: if line has 3 `;` then replace `;` using `;;` once (i.e. replace only first `;` using `;;`)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=';')

df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(
    lambda x: np.roll(x, 1) if np.isnan(x[3]) else x, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   var1  var2   var3 var4  var5
0     1    10   john   40  56.0
1     2   NaN   mary   34  78.0
2     3  90.0  smith   52  45.0
```

Answer (score 0):

about the particular bug you have in the end, you'll see by opening your 'output.csv' that it does not contains anything, that's why the error is thrown when you try to open it (*by using pd.read_csv i suppose ?*).

If you add a `print` line in your reading loop, you'll notice that each line is a 1-element list of a string with your values seperated by semicolons instead of a 5-elements list of values.

It's because you have to tell your reader method that you're using a semicolon as delimiter (instead of `,` which is the default one).
So if you specify the delimiter `;` for your reader and writer, it will create a new csv file with only the lines without missing values :

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv',newline='') as fin, open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = ';')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = ';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        if len(row) > 4:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Hope this helps